# How to cancel token id and subscription on Firebase? I can't close the session

Tags: android, firebase, messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try with this:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeToTopic("mytopic");
```

and

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("mytopic");
```

but they do not work.

I need cancel token too. Is someone trying to implement `firebase` success?

Comment: how have you checked they do not work ?

Comment: Yes, in the logchat he show me both with FirebaseMessaging.getInstance () unsubscribeToTopic ("MyTopic."); & FirebaseMessaging.getInstance () unsubscribeFromTopic ("MyTopic."); as with
  FirebaseMessaging.getInstance () subscribeToTopic ( "MyTopic.");  "succeds topic". I do not understand.

Comment: There is no method unsubscribeToTopic() did you mean subscribeToTopic?

Comment: I know that unsuscribetotopic does not exist. I try with unsuscribefromtopic and the result is the same, still no t working.